# Vue JSX with typescript not working

Tags: webpack, vue.js, jsx, vue-loader, ts-loader

When using standalone TSX files containing JSX, everything works perfect. 
My webpack configuration:

```
{ 
      test: /\.tsx$/, 
      loader: 'babel-loader!ts-loader'
}
```

And tsconfig.json jsx option set to "preserve" so that Typescript will ignore JSX compilation to be handled by babel. Makes perfect sense.

But when I use the same recipe for Vue-loader it does not work:

```
{
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue-loader',
      options: {
        loaders: {
          "tsx": "babel-loader!ts-loader"
        }
      }
    }
```

And the example component:

```
<script lang="tsx">
import { VNode, CreateElement } from "vue";

export default {
    functional: true,
    render (h: CreateElement): VNode {
       return (
           <div>
              <span>Working?</span>
          </div>
      );
   }
}
</script>
```

Error log:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     functional: true,
|     render: function (h) {
|         return (Working ? /span>
|             < /div>
```

It seems that ts-loader somehow does not respect the JSX preserve here.  When looking at the error log / output it seems that ts-loader tries to parse the JSX or try to compile a regular expression.

I haven't been able to pin point the exact issue but when debugging dist/index.js: 152 I can clearly see ouput is malformed and the compiler tries to compile JSX rather than ignoring.

```
function getEmit(rawFilePath, filePath, instance, loader) {
    var output = instance.languageService.getEmitOutput(filePath);
    console.log("Ouput JSX malformed?", output);
    loader.clearDependencies();
    loader.addDependency(rawFilePath);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Any `.babelrc` config?